# How to stop teams from being creating a new XAML based build definition

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are on the way to migrate all the XAML based builds to vNext build. I want to stop the teams to create a new XAML based build at this point of time or even in the future. How to do that?

Comment: Looks like security does not distinguish XAML build definitions and vNext...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may ask Administrator to stop the Build Service in TFS Administration Console--XAML Build Configuration.

Comment: but that will stop all the current builds in XAML. I just want to stop the users to create new ones.

Comment: The security setting can't distinguish XAML build and vNext build, if deny the permission to create XAML build, the vNext build can't be created either.

Comment: thanks for the info. Not sure how to restrict them from creating a build def.

Comment: Deny the Edit build definition permission will restrict them from creating a build def, but that will also prevent from creating vNext build definition. :-(

Comment: I think MS should think about it. If you want people to use new build systems then there should be someway to stop creating new ones. :(

Comment: I've submitted a User Voice at website below, you can vote it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17295757-stop-teams-from-being-creating-a-new-xaml-based-bu

Comment: 2 Vote from my end :). I will mark this as answered.

Comment: What's wrong with monitoring Xaml builds and talking to people. You cant solve a people problem with technology. You might want to start reducing the a) the number of agents and b) the capability of the agents. This will produce a contention in Xaml builds that will not be in Team Build. People will gravitate to the easy and painless option.